# Use relative root for i18n in presenter files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

Working with a file like `app/presenters/foo.rb`, I want to be able to have an i18n key `foo.whatever` and reference it inside `foo.rb` as `I18n.t('.whatever')`, in a way that's similar to doing it with views.

Is that possible? I dug through the i18n guide on Rails and searched through the internet ("add relative roots to i18n") pretty thoroughly to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `foo` a class or a module? you could make all your presenters extend a base module with something like:

```
def t(key)
  scope = "presenters.#{self.class.to_s.underscore.gsub('/', '.')}"
  I18n.t(key, scope: scope, default: I18n.t(key))
end
```

EDIT: changed to be correct Rails syntax and work with module namespaces